# Exit all trades at 1% profit of account balance or 1 dollar

Tags: pine-script

I am a newbie who just started learning pine coding.  I am developing a simple strategy of multiple buys and sells based on market flow.  How can I exit all open trades when my account balance reaches a net profit of either 1% percentage of the account balance or just at 1 dollar profit?

```
//buy-sell conditions
buy_signal  = close >= open[1]
sell_signal = close <= open[1]

//execution code
strategy.entry('Buy',  strategy.long,  when = buy_signal)
strategy.entry('Sell', strategy.short, when = sell_signal)

//collective trades exit code
if ( )
    strategy.close_all()
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `strategy.position_avg_price` to get your average position price. Then calculate your target profit price using this variable.

```
long_profit_price = strategy.position_avg_price * 1.01  // 1% profit

if (strategy.position_size > 0)
    strategy.exit("Buy Exit", "Buy", limit=long_profit_price)
```